# Pass Text to JavaScript with document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, html, getelementbyid

I am trying to pass text to JavaScript via `document.getElementById`. Specifically, I am trying to pass the value of the ID (set to "Jason_Example_12" in the example below). I can pass values that are integers, but am unable to pass text.

I have considered using innerHtml, but that does not get the value, it only gets what is between the `<li>` tags.

Any help would be appreciated!

Thanks!

```
<script type='text/javascript'>  

function ajaxAssignFull() {
var assignment_string = 
var assignment_string = document.getElementById('assignment_string_full').value
alert(assignment_string);   
}

</script>

<li id="assignment_string_full" onclick='ajaxAssignFull()' value="Jason_Example_12"><a 
href="#">Jason Example</a></li>
```

Comment: `li` elements don't have value attributes. Input elements do.

Comment: can you use data-attributes and jquery? if so that might be a good route for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Value` wil make your html invalid on li, as li does not have a `value` attribute. Instead try using html5 data-*. You can always use `getAttribute('value')` but be discouraged to do so since `value` is invalid on li.

#### Html

```
<li id="assignment_string_full" onclick='ajaxAssignFull()' data-value="Jason_Example_12"><a 
href="#">Jason Example</a></li>
```

#### Script

```
var assignment_string = document.getElementById('assignment_string_full').getAttribute('data-value');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `getAttribute('value')`

```
function ajaxAssignFull() {
    var assignment_string = document.getElementById('assignment_string_full');
    alert(assignment_string.getAttribute('value'));
}
```

**Edit:**

Use data-attribute is a good way.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementById('assignment_string_full').attributes.value.nodeValue
```